# Left-right align

Tags: android, android-layout

How it is possible to layout controls like this?
[image]

By another words - one `TextView` aligned to the left side and the second one to the right side. Of course red layouts should be stretched according to the screen width. I have no idea how to do this in the most nice way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the below layout for your requirement::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#ffffff" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"  android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This will only work if, for each row, the left and right `TextView`s are the same height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayouts. Then just position your textviews like

```
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Here is the link for this type of layouts:

[Android Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the whole view into one RelativeLayout and use layout_alignParentLeft, layout_alignParentRight to stick Textview to the left and right of the view then layout_alignBaseline to keep Textview on each side level. Then layout_below to put the next line of Textview.

Alternatively, you can use LinearLayout to layout_width="match_parent" then turn red box into RelativeLayout using the same method above.

However, I suggest you check each type of the layout to see characteristic of each container then decide which is the most fit for your view as a whole but keep in mind that the more view/layout you have on the screen will effect the performance on some devices. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout, but one view of these two view in same row should be of some fixed width. If you are sure that right view wont take width greater than some width, then you can also assign wrap_content to width, but if second view may take full screen width, then its necessary to assign some fixed width to layout.

So set LayoutParams to Left and Right view as follows:
LeftView:

Layout_width=fill_parent, Layout_height=wrap_content, layout_toLeftOf=@+id/rightView,

SecondVIew:

Layout_width=wrap_content, Layout_height=wrap_content, layout_alignParentRight= true